# Is gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails" different from what I see in getbootstrap.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a first time railer and using twitter-bootstrap-rails.

Some Less variables on http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ seem not to work. And the code generated by the navbar helper differs a lot from the code on the getbootstrap.com components page.

It is kind of hard to guess how it works if I can't use the docs at the official bootstrap website. Or am I doing something terribly wrong? I just followed the steps on seyhunak's github to install twitter-bootstrap-rails.

How can I see which version of bootstrap is the gem using? Should I keep using bootstrap as a gem if I want to use it as documented on getbootstrap.com?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually, Rails prefers sass, which you can use bootstrap-sass which has all the varibles to use

make sure you configured Rails to work with LESS appropriatly

Comment: It seems I have, because on the bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less I can change some variables successfully. e.g. @navbarBackground: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); works.

Comment: I switched to bootstrap-sass -- works perfectly now. Thanks @nick-ginanto